# How can I make a Python module's __init__.py delegate its help() to a sibling file?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

Currently we have a Python library that looks something like:

```
Jupiter/
  __init__.py
  Ganymede.py
  Callisto.py
```

`Ganymede.py` in turn contains functions `Foo()`, `Bar()`, and so forth. Our existing scripts use these functions via

```
from Jupiter import Ganymede
# later in the program...
Ganymede.Foo()
```

I would like to reorganize things so that the directory looks more like

```
Jupiter/
  __init__.py
  Ganymede/
    __init__.py
    functions.py
  Callisto/
    __init__.py
    functions.py
```

**without breaking or modifying** any existing scripts that use Jupiter.

If `Ganymede/__init__.py` uses the import syntax described in ["The import system" documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules):

```
from .functions import *
```

then `Foo()` and `Bar()` end up in Ganymede's namespace, but the `help()` for Ganymede doesn't mention them.

```
>>> from Jupiter import Ganymede
>>> dir(Ganymede)
['Bar', 'Foo', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'functions']
>>> help(Ganymede)
Help on package Jupiter.Ganymede in Jupiter:

NAME
    Jupiter.Ganymede

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    functions

FILE
    x:\yadda\yadda\ganymede\__init__.py
```

I would really, really like `help(Ganymede)` to automatically list all the available functions and classes.

I suppose I could `execfile("functions.py")` from `Ganymede/__init__.py` but I feel like there must be some cleaner way to do this. Or is there not?

I need something that works in both Python 2.7.15 and 3.5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `__all__` in `__init__.py`.

---

If you've already got an `__all__` in `functions.py`, you can just import it:

```
from .functions import *
from .functions import __all__
```

---

If you're merging multiple modules together, you have to get a bit more verbose

```
from .functions import *
from .classes import *
from . import functions
from . import classes
__all__ = functions.__all__ + classes.__all__
```

---

Or, of course, you can always be explicit:

```
from .functions import *
__all__ = ['spam', 'eggs']
```

---

Or, if you want to build it dynamically:

```
from .functions import *
from . import functions
__all__ = [name for name in dir(functions) if not name.startswith('_')]
```

… or (pretty hacky—but sometimes useful if you have a `__init__.py` that gathers names from a lot of submodules and does nothing else) …

```
from .functions import *
__all__ = [name for name in globals() if not name.startswith('_')]
```

… or you can get really clever and do things the way, e.g., [`multiprocessing`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3/Lib/multiprocessing/__init__.py) does:<sup>1</sup>

```
from . import functions
__all__ = [name for name in functions if not name.startswith('_')]
globals().update({name: getattr(functions, name) for name in __all__})
```

---

Keep in mind that `__all__` will also affect what happens when someone does a `from Ganymede import *` (in fact, [that's the main purpose of `__all__`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=__all__#importing-from-a-package)), and what `inspect` and other tools report as the public members of your package.

I'm not sure the behavior of `help` in the absence of `__all__` is documented anywhere (interactive `help` works is only lightly documented in general…), and it's not quite the same as what `import` considers public.

---

<sub>1. Well, `multiprocessing` is actually a lot more clever/hacky; it's pulling the attributes not out of a submodule, but out of a dynamic singleton attribute of that submodule that gets set differently on the main vs. child processes, and changes some of the top-level functions of the package accordingly…</sub>

Comment: Is there a way for me to achieve this without having to explictly list every member of `functions.py` in its `__all__` (ie, to get the find-everything-automatically behavior of `help()`)?

Comment: @Crashworks Yes, if you don't mind getting a bit hacky. Give me a second and I'll edit it.

Comment: wouldn't `vars` be better here? When would you ever want sometihing in `set(dir()) - set(vars)`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh, I think I've got what you're asking. If the module has a custom `__dir__` and `__getattr__` to export dynamic public members that aren't in its `__dict__`, why would you want to ignore them?

Comment: Wow, thank you for all that research!  I'm grateful for your time on this, but it's convinced me that I ought to just put the contents of `functions.py` into `__init__.py` and be done with it.